# Elaboration of Thm. 1.1 in chapter V in Richard H. Crowell.

Tags: proof-explanation

The theorem and its proof is given below:

[image]

But I do not understand why $(\rho i)_{*} = $ identity implies that $\rho_{*}$ is onto. Could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: Every function with a right inverse is necessarily a [surjection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function#Surjections_as_right_invertible_functions)

Comment: And if it is with left inverse, it is 1-1?@J.W.Tanner

Comment: [Yes, that's true](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Injection_iff_Left_Inverse)